# Jquery datepicker - Pass date array from Controller MVC

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, datepicker

I have created a List containing available dates and serialized it into json:

```
List<string> dates = new List<string>();   

foreach(BookingDates itm in model.availableDates)
{
    dates.Add(itm.expDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"));
}

model.datesStr = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(dates);
```

I then pass model data to jquery and try to pass the dates to the datepicker:

```
var availableDates = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@Model.datesStr));
alert(availableDates);

function available(date) {
    dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
    if ($.inArray(dmy, availableDates) != -1) {
        return [true, "ui-available", "Available"];
    } 
    else {
        return [false, "ui-unavailable", "unAvailable"];
    }
}
```

The datepicker does not populate with dates.
If however I type the dates, it does:

```
var availableDates = ["20-11-2016","17-12-2016"];
```

The only difference I have noticed is the result of my alert when dates typed as above is:

20-11-2016,17-12-2016

Opposed to resulting the following when I use the json:

["20-11-2016","17-12-2016"]

I have also tried declaring the var as an array:

```
var availableDates = [];
availableDates = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@Model.datesStr));
```

again with no success implementing the json. SHould I be in some way converting my json to string separated with comma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize` method will convert your list to a string. If you want a javascript array for your client side code, you should change the view model property from string to a collection (array/list).

```
public class YourViewModel
{
  public List<string> Dates { set;get;}
  //Other properties 
}
```

And in your action method,

```
foreach(BookingDates itm in model.availableDates)
{
    vm.Dates.Add(itm.expDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"));
}
return View(vm);
```

Now in the razor view,

```
@model YourViewModel
<script>
   var availableDates = @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.JsonJsonConvert
                                            .SerializeObject(Model.Dates))
   console.log(availableDates);
</script>
```